# 2 stacked div's with background gradients, not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, background

I have an issue where I want to have to divs that act as a background. they basically wrap the entire page. both have the same gradient set as their background-image. the problem is that on div displays the gradient perfectly fine, but the other is just white.

html:

```
<div class="bg bg-base">
  <div id="bg-animation" class="bg bg-animation">
    <div class="layer-content">
       <!--content here-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bg-base {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #5533ff, #008dff, #00bdff, #00e0dd, #a4fbc9);
}

.bg-animation {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #5533ff, #008dff, #00bdff, #00e0dd, #a4fbc9);
}

.layer-content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

I'm doing some opacity animations with the top gradient, that's why I need 2 of them on top of each other. but if say, I set the opacity of the top gradient to 0, the bottom one isn't there. if I add a `height: 5000px;` to the bg-base, it does show up.

Answer (score -1):

Kill the absolute positioning:

https://jsfiddle.net/cathead/1nbjdp05/4/

```
.bg {
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  xposition: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```